# How to get filtered item by value index in C# Dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net

I am trying to write a method which should return the item value based on value index and condition.

For example, in the below, if I pass index value as 0, it should return keys and first value from integer array which is not having value 5.

```
public static Dictionary<string, int[]> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
    {
        {"A", [1,0,3] },
        {"B", [5,1,5] },
        {"C", [7,11,5] },
        {"D", [0,1,5]},
        {"E", [14,0,5] },
        {"F", [5,1,5] }
    };
```

**Expected O/P:**

if I pass index value 0, and condition as != 5 then O/P should be

```
    {
        {"A", 1 },
        {"C", 7 },
        {"D", 0 },
        {"E", 14}
    };
```

Comment: What's your method signature? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you please show us your attempts and what is not working for you?

Comment: The code above doesn't compile and is invalid.

Comment: If you are interested in getting help, providing valid code is kinda a good start.  Each line of your dictionary initialization should look something like `{"A", new []{1,0,3} },`.  When you say _"Expected O/P:"_, what's O/P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this in two steps:

1. Get those items that do not start with `5`

```cs
var res = _dict.Where(a => a.Value[0] !=5);
```

2. Then populate a new **Dictionary** with the remaining keys and the first entry in their integer array

```cs
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int[]> keyValuePair in res)
{
    result.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value[0]);
}
```

or using **LINQ**

```cs
result = res.ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue.Key, keyValue => keyValue.Value[valueIndex]);
```

---

Complete code would look something like

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, int[]> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
{
    {"A", new int[] {1,0,3 } },
    {"B", new int[] {5,1,5} },
    {"C", new int[] {7,11,5} },
    {"D", new int[] {0,1,5}},
    {"E", new int[] {14,0,5} },
    {"F", new int[] {5,1,5} }
};

static Dictionary<string, int> GetResult(int valueIndex, Func<KeyValuePair<string, int[]>, bool> predicate) =>
            _dict.Where(predicate)
                 .ToDictionary(keyValue => keyValue.Key, keyValue => keyValue.Value[valueIndex]);
```

`GetResult(valueIndex: 0, predicate: a => a.Value[0] != 5)` then gives the result you want

```
{
    {"A", 1 },
    {"C", 7 },
    {"D", 0 },
    {"E", 14}
};
```

Comment: When the index doesn't exist in the array, it will throw an error `IndexOutOfRangeException`. It would be best to check this first.

Answer (score 1):

One line code using `LINQ`

```
var result = _dict.Where(x => x.Value[0] != 5).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value[0]);
```